# How do I use SWIG to expose a public inlined c++ method?

Tags: c++, swig

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class bar
{
public:
    bar();
    void helloworld(int date) 
         { std::cout << "Hello world, the date is: " << date << std::endl; }
};
```

What would I have to do in the interface file to expose the inlined helloworld() method? I looked into the %inline, but it doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for, which is exposing this as a callable method.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There is no difference, so inlining is not the issue. As other comments ask, post the error(s) you get, and the .i file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```swig
/* bar_module.i */
%module bar_module
%{
#include "bar.h"
%}
%include "bar.h"
```

```c++
/* bar.h */
#include <iostream>
class bar
{
public:
    bar();
    void helloworld(int date) 
         { std::cout << "Hello world, the date is: " << date << std::endl; }
};
```

```c++
/* bar.cc */
#include "bar.h"
bar::bar() {}
```

```python
# test.py
import bar_module
bar_module.bar().helloworld(47)
```

```sh
# Build commands
swig -o bar_module_wrap.cc -python -c++ bar_module.i
g++ -o bar_module_wrap.os -c -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 bar_module_wrap.cc
g++ -o bar.os -c -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 bar.cc
g++ -o _bar_module.so -shared bar_module_wrap.os bar.os

# Test command
python test.py
```

```
# Output
Hello world, the date is: 47
```